# How to route JWT Token request from client app, formed with double slashes?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, bearer-token

Currently we have a WPF client app that request bearer tokens to an ASP MVC app using OAuth.

This configuration takes place at startup when an endpoint is defined:

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
   TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
   Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
   AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
   AllowInsecureHttp = true
};
```

The client WPF application requests tokens by issuing a POST request to [resourceBaseAddress/Token]. The request content I will assume is not relevante to my question.

The problem is that my "resourceBaseAddress" contains a trailing forward slash, so the request is formed in a way such as http://contoso.com//Token (note the double slash). And it currently works.

But now that we are migrating to ASP.NET Core and by consequence I had to add a controller with  (Jwt) Token action, I am experiencing problems to route this request with double forward slashes.

As I cannot change code on client app, how can I configure this controller method properly?

Answer (score 0):

How about a middleware that rewrites the request path? Did you try something like this?

Example:

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var url = context.Request.Path.Value;

    if (url.EndsWith("//Token"))
    {
        // rewrite and continue processing
        context.Request.Path = "/Token";
    }

    await next();
});

app.UseRouting();
```

And a simple controller like this:

```cs
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TokenController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post()
    {
        return "Token";
    }
}
```